# Load models through helper file causes blank screen

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model, controller

I am doing a system based on the Codeigniter framework and use alot of data from databases.

The thing that is nagging me is that in every function I need to declare what you see down below inside the square box. Every time I create a new function with viewable content I need to fill this in all over again. Is there no way to put this into a simple way? For example as you in normal php can:

```
include_once 'topmenu_dbs';
```

Because tight now I stand before the task to add another database query to the line-up and that would right now have me to change all functions individually which will take some time. And if I need to do something more in the future the same trip is needed.

```
public function entre()
{
    $this->load->model('mylibrary');

    $data['crew_pizza_book']=$this->mylibrary->crew_pizza_book();
    $data['lanare']=$this->mylibrary->lanare();
    $data['kiosk_rec']=$this->mylibrary->kiosk_rec();

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('topmenu', $data);
    $this->load->view('entre');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

**Based on the help I have recieved so far here comes an update to the issue:**

---

I added a helper file (init_helper.php) and place it in application/helpers

```
<?php

function init_data()
{
    $CI=get_instance();

    $CI->load->model('mylibrary');

    $data['crew_pizza_book']=$this->mylibrary->crew_pizza_book(); 
    $data['lanare']=$this->mylibrary->lanare();                   
    $data['kiosk_rec']=$this->mylibrary->kiosk_rec(); 

    return $data;
}

?>
```

In config/autoload.php I added the new helper file.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'init');
```

In my model "mylibrary" it looks like this:

```
<?php 
class Mylibrary extends CI_Model
{

    function crew_pizza_book(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM crew_pizza_book ORDER BY pizza");
        return $query->result();
    }

    function lanare(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM crew_lanare ORDER BY id ASC");
        return $query->result();
    }

    function kiosk_rec(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM crew_kiosk_rec");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
?>
```

I tried testing this with a simple function:

```
public function test()
{
    print_r(init_data());
}
```

This generates a blank screen.

When I try to set static values to the arrays like this:

```
$data['crew_pizza_book']="a"; 
$data['lanare']="b";                   
$data['kiosk_rec']="c";
```

I get a good print:

```
Array ( [crew_pizza_book] => a [lanare] => b [kiosk_rec] => c )
```

Comment: `$CI=get_instance();` should be `$CI=&get_instance();`.  Also `$this->mylibrary->crew_pizza_book()` should be `$CI->mylibrary->crew_pizza_book()` . Same with other two functions. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Now we're cooking! Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this so:

First create a helper file called say, init_helper.php and add a function inside it:

```
function init_data()
{
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->model("my_model");
    $data['crew_pizza_book'] = $CI->my_model->crew_pizza_book(); 
    $data['lanare'] = $CI->my_model->lanare();                   
    $data['kiosk_rec'] = $CI->my_model->kiosk_rec();    
    return $data;
}
```

Then `autoload` this `helper` in `config/autoload.php`

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Helper Files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
*/

$autoload['helper'] = array('init'); //ignore the '_helper.php' portion of the filename
```

Now in your code, call it as:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('topmenu', init_data());   
$this->load->view('entre');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Comment: Awsome. Exactly what I am looking for. However. When I apply this I get a PHP error: "Undefined variable: init_data" I did as above apart from changing "my_model" to "mylibrary" that is my model in use here.

Comment: @SimonBlanck - Once you have autoloaded the init_helper.php, are you able to call `print_r(init_data());` anywhere in your controller or view?

Comment: When I tried to do as you suggested I got a blank white screen. Tried both in controller and view.

Comment: @SimonBlanck - I just created this in my codeigniter installation, (I did not use a model because I do not know how your model works), but when i do print_r(init_data()) - I get `Array ( [crew_pizza_book] => a [lanare] => b[kiosk_rec] => c) `

Comment: @SimonBlanck - also `init_data` cannot be `undefined variable`, like you mentioned in the comment. It has to be a function...

Comment: Okey. So I tried the same thing and set the arrays to something specific and removed the `$ci->load->model("mylibrary");` involved and that made me get the same as you. That means something with the call of model is wrong then.

Comment: @SimonBlanck -yup, I thought the same thing... Once you fix that the rest should work as intended

Comment: Or rather when messing about now I notice that adding `$ci->load->model("mylibrary");` did not cause the blank screen. Its when I add the rest `$data['lanare'] = $this->mylibrary->lanare();` for example. That is when I get blank screen.

Comment: @SimonBlanck - I meant that one of the functions crew_pizza_book(), lanare() or kiosk_rec() is causing the issue...